# Using SCSS 'current selector' feature to match all class names starting with same text

Tags: sass

Suppose, we have `HTML` with similar name classes.

```html
<div class="header-name">NAME</div>
<div class="header-description">DESCRIPTION</div>
```

I want to use `SCSS's` `current selector` feature to style them differently:

```
.header {
   &-* {} // doesn't work

   &-name {} // works fine

   &-description {} // works fine
}
```

How to match all `header-*`-like classes using `SCSS`?
I don't want to solve this like that:

```
.header {
   &-name, &-description {} // I don't want that solution, because in real case I have like 20 such selectors

   &-name {}

   &-description {}
}
```

I know I can use strict `CSS` here:

```css
div[class^='header-'] {}
```

But I wonder if it is possible inside one block without repeating

Comment: your question is little confusing , will you please rephrase it?

Comment: @Supercool really difficult to do that :D I tried to rephrase it, but no idea if it changed anything

Comment: like you want to style name and description differently ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that it's possible in SCSS. The most closest solution that I have come up with is using a loop combined with the variable:

```
$values: (
 'value1',
 'value2'
);

@each $value in $values {
  .header-#{$value} {
    // Your code here
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

Better yet: Convert it into a mixin:

```
@mixin all($base, $names...) {
  @each $name in $names {
    .#{$base}-#{$name} {
      @content;
    }
  }
}
```

And call it with:

```
$values: (
 'value1',
 'value2'
);
$base: 'header';

@include all($base, $values) {
  // Your code here
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Sass masters exist indeed :D